# Option value not changing with user selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a form with the following dropdown selection menu in HTML:

```
<div class="input-field col s4">
    <select id="disposition" required>
        <option value="No_Sale" id="noSale">No Sale</option>
        <option value="Sale" id="yeahSale">Sale</option>
        <option value="Unreachable" id="noContact">Unreachable</option>
        <option value="Call_Back" id="callBack">Call Back</option>
    </select>
    <label>Disposition</label>
</div>
```

The above snippet for dispositions should affect whether or not other form elements are disabled. However, I cannot seem to get the value to change on user input.

Here is the javascript with jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(){
    console.log(disposition);
    console.log($("#yeahSale").selected == true);

    if ($("#yeahSale").selected == true) {
        $("#fund").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

For both `$("#disposition").val()` and `$("#yeahSale").selected`, the `console.log` returns

> "No_Sale"

and false when I click on the form element and select

> "Sale."

The first thing I tried was:

```
    if (disposition == "Sale")
```

I have also tried:

```
var disposition = $("#disposition").find(":selected").text();
```

I've been searching stack exchange and google for answers for almost an hour but I haven't any success so far. My apologies if I just completely missed an extant question that's already been solved.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `if (dispositon == "Sale")...`

Comment: I'm sorry, @Banzay. I forgot to include that I already tried that. I have updated the post accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: [Check this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40871448/5236174)

Comment: I think you are getting too caught up in giving the options `id`s and checking for `selected` with them. Typically with a `select`, you just worry about the *value* of the selected `option`  and/or the *indexes* of the `options` and make decisions from there.

Comment: @wiljago. You've bound function to event that comes on whole `$(document)`. you need to catch event on `$("#disposition")` only. I mean this: `$("#disposition").on('change',...`

Comment: @Banzay thanks but I tried that also, and when I did it that way the change event wasn't recognized at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#disposition").val()` gives you the value of selected option.

So you simply want to put condition according to the value you got selected.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#disposition', function(){
    
    /* 
        If you want to put condition based on 
        option with specific id is selected or not  then
        
        if($("#yeahSale").is(':selected')) { 
           
        }
   */

    if ($("#disposition").val() == 'Sale') {
        // Do here what you want to do
        // $("#fund").removeAttr('disabled');
        console.log("Sale Selected");
    } else {
        console.log("Selected Option is: "+ $("#disposition").val());
    }
  
    //Get Id attr of selected option
    console.log("Id of selected option is: " + $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id'));
   
    // Check weather option with specific Id is selected or not:
    console.log($("#yeahSale").is(':selected'));
   
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field col s4">
    <select id="disposition" required>
        <option value="No_Sale" id="noSale">No Sale</option>
        <option value="Sale" id="yeahSale">Sale</option>
        <option value="Unreachable" id="noContact">Unreachable</option>
        <option value="Call_Back" id="callBack">Call Back</option>
    </select>
    <label>Disposition</label>
</div>
```

If you want to get id attribute of selected option you can use this

```
$(this).find('option:selected').attr('id')
```

If you want to see option with ID yeahSale is selected or not than try this:

```
$("#yeahSale").is(':selected')
```

Comment: thanks! Totally weird. In the console log it returns "Sale Selected" and that $("#disposition").val() is "Sale." But for console.log($("#yeahSale").selected == true) it still returns false, and for $("#disposition").find(":selected").val() it returns "No_Sale."

The .removeAttr isn't working now, but this solution might be enough to twist it into functioning.

Thanks! I'll work with this and if I get it functional I'll mark this as answered and update the post.

Comment: //console.log("Sale Selected"); is written in my code that's why you see that. and in else part  console.log  prints the selected value.

Comment: Yeah, that part I understand. It's just weird that $("#disposition).val() is changing but that option value isn't coming up as selected. 

I had added that stuff in after doing it with just $("#disposition).val() and found that wasn't working.

The main thing that seems to be different in your solution is the 'select' in the document on change code. I hadn't been including that, but it obviously makes a big difference.

Comment: thanks @lahar-shah! sorry for the late update -- later that afternoon i was asked to scrap the entire thing and remake it in infopath and sharepoint instead. but your solution totally worked when i tested it today.

Answer (score 0):

```
var disposition = $('#disposition').val();
$('#disposition').change(function() {
    disposition = $(this).val();
    console.log(disposition);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @maestroosram. Unfortunately I got the same result.

Comment: @wiljago I think all the problem is where you override the `disposition` variable (and do the `console.log()`). Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="input-field col s4">
 <select id="disposition">
    <option value="No_Sale">No Sale</option>
    <option value="Sale">Sale</option>
    <option value="Unreachable">Unreachable</option>
    <option value="Call_Back">Call Back</option>
  </select>
   <label>Disposition</label>
  </div>
<script>
  $(document).on('change', function(){
   alert($("#disposition").val());
  console.log($("#yeahSale").selected == true);

   if ($("#yeahSale").selected == true) {
    $("#fund").removeAttr('disabled');
   }
  });

  tested and found it working
```

Comment: i guess the issue with option's id

Answer (score -1):

All you need is `disposition.value` and an `onchange` event.

The script below will acknowledge user input and return the updated `disposition.value` whenever a new selection is made:

```js
var disposition = document.getElementById('disposition');
disposition.addEventListener('change', function(){console.log(disposition.value);}, false);
```

```html
<select id="disposition" required>
<option value="No_Sale">No Sale</option>
<option value="Sale">Sale</option>
<option value="Unreachable">Unreachable</option>
<option value="Call_Back">Call Back</option>
</select>
```